# Move UITableView with UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am trying to mix an `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` with an `UITableView`.

What I would like to do is, while I am doing the swipe gesture, move at the same time the `UITableView` outside the window and refresh the table data.

I am going to show you with images...

This is my view:

[My View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDurI.png)

And I would like to get something like this:

[Desired View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avDXQ.png)

I am able to move the table when the swipe gesture is ended, but not while I am doing the gesture, and that is what I want.

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    swipeToRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeToGroup:)];
    [swipeToRight setDelegate:self];
    [swipeToRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [[self table]addGestureRecognizer:swipeToRight];

    swipeToLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeToContact:)];
    [swipeToLeft setDelegate:self];
    [swipeToLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [[self table]addGestureRecognizer:swipeToLeft];
}

- (void)changeToGroup:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGesture
{
    NSLog(@"Right to group");
    [self updateTableData]; //Here I move the table and update data.
    [segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
}

- (void)changeToContact:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGesture
{
    NSLog(@"Left to contact");
    [self updateTableData]; //Here I move the table and update data.
    [segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];
}
```

I thought that I could do it with UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan, adding the animations inside that event, but I can't receive it...

Could anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!!.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

use `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)]; 
[recognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
[recognizer setDelegate:self];
[[self table]addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

and in

```
- (void) handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    UIView *view = self.tableView;
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // remember where the pan started
        //panGestureOrigin is a CGPoint variable
        panGestureOrigin = view.frame.origin;
        //optional to keep an enum to keep direction
        //self.panDirection = MenuPanDirectionNone;
    }
    CGPoint translatedPoint = [recognizer translationInView:view];
        if(translatedPoint.x > 20) {

            //self.panDirection = MenuPanDirectionRight;
            [self handleRightPan:recognizer];
        } else if(translatedPoint.x < 0) {

            //self.panDirection = MenuPanDirectionLeft;
            [self handleLeftPan:recognizer];
        }
}

- (void) handleRightPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    //animate here

    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        NSLog(@"Right to group");
       [self updateTableData]; //Here I move the table and update data.
       [segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
    }
}

- (void) handleLeftPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    // animate here
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"Left to contact");
       [self updateTableData]; //Here I move the table and update data.
       [segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];
    }
}
```